# Mark Liferay Notification as Read programmatically

Tags: notifications, liferay

I want the notification to be marked as read after the user Approves or Rejects the Notification. Here on click of approve or reject I am calling an action url. The method is called Successfully but the notification is still displayed as not read. The Notification screen is as below:

[image: Approve Reject Notification]

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.